# Rotate nohup output

Tags: 12.04, log, nohup

I'm working with weblogic 10.3.5 under ubuntu 12.04.

Weblogic is started using

```
nohup ./startWebLogic.sh >Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/logs/AdminServer.out 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

It's working fine and now I would like to rotate `AdminServer.out` using `logrotate` but it seems it's not so easy to do.  Searching on internet it is not very clear to understand if it is possible or not.

I tried using the `copytruncate` options.  When the logrotate is executing the size of the file becomes 0 but returns to original size after the first 'write' of the server.

Also tried renaming the file.  The server still writes to the renamed file.

It seems the server only have a pointer to a file independently of it's name or size.

So ... is there a solution ?  Using logrotate or not.

--EDIT--

I also tried with

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p tmp
if [ ! -p tmp/weblogic.fifo ]; then
    mkfifo tmp/weblogic.fifo
fi
tail -f tmp/weblogic.fifo >> Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/logs/AdminServer.out &
nohup ./startWebLogic.sh > /home/me/tmp/weblogic.fifo 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

I don't know if it is proper but ... there is at least one problem : sometimes, it hangs up writing to the file.  Sometimes a few seconds but after a while (even before the server has started) ... indefinitely !

So I cannot test the logrotate.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/221337/logrotate-successful-original-file-goes-back-to-original-size

Comment: I already read that.  So if I can't kill the process (and I can't kill weblogic) there is no solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was eventually so simple

```
nohup ./startWebLogic.sh 2>&1 </dev/null | cat >> AdminServer.out &
```

and now the `AdminServer.out` can be rotated with `logrotate` **and** the `copytruncate` option.

Comment: I din't see how it rotate but apparently it is serving my needs. Rotation will come after because I am relying on Log4J2 for logs in my .jar app. If you get any update you can let me know. But I for now I wanted to let you know that your reply helped me

Answer (score 5):

Unlearn the need for `logrotate`.  You don't need `logrotate` in the first place.  This is a problem that has been solved since the middle 1990s.

Get yourself one or more of:

- Dan Bernstein's [`multilog`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html) from [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), or Bruce Guenter's [`multilog`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/multilog.8.html) from [daemontools-encore](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/), or Adam Sampson's `multilog` from [freedt](http://offog.org/code/freedt/), or
- Laurent Bercot's [`s6-log`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-log.html) from [s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/), or
- Gerrit Pape's [`svlogd`](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html) from [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), or
- Wayne Marshall's [`tinylog`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=tinylog.8) from [perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/), or
- my [`cyclog`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/cyclog.html) from [nosh](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh.html).

and send script standard output and standard error through a pipe to their standard input, in the normal way:

```
./startWebLogic.sh 2>&1 | cyclog logs/
```

They will write a set of automatically cycled, rotateable-on-demand, strictly size-capped logs in a directory that you specify, with no need for any additional log rotation programs at all.  None of them need any superuser privileges.  (In fact, far from needing or expecting superuser privileges *it is best practice* in their most widely known use case, logging dæmon output, to run them under unprivileged accounts.)

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Don't use logrotate or newsyslog in this century.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/do-not-use-logrotate.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with the first multilog.  But I don't understand how it's working.  I tried for ex. ls -l | multilog t s10485760 n5 '!tai64nlocal' tmp.  But nothing appears in the tmp folder.

Comment: With multilog, directory names must start with a dot or a slash.